# SAPUI5 table sorting not working

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a UI5 table. I want to sort my table with "Quatity" field (ascending order). For that, in handlebeforerebind table method, I have used this code:

```
var mBindingParams = oEvent.getParameter("bindingParams");
mBindingParams.sorter = "Quantity";
```

I am not able to understand how can I use this sorter method on my table? On another attempt, I have also tried this:

```
var aTable = this.getView().byId("myTableId");
aTable.sortProperty = "Quantity";
```

VIEW:

```
<Table>
    <columns>
        <Column>
            <header>
                <Text text="Quantity">
            </header>
        </Column>    
        <Column>
            <header>
                <Text text="Order">
            </header>
        </Column>
    </columns>
    <ColumnListItem type="Navigation">
        <Link class="sapMLabelBold" text="{Quantity}"></Link>
        <Link class="sapMLabelBold" text="{Order}"></Link>
    </ColumnListItem>
</Table>
```

Somehow it is not working. Can anyone help me with this issue? Thanks!

Comment: can you add the view part where you are creating the table.

Comment: Hi Naveen, 

its just a simple table. I have added it to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it in an easier way. I provided sorter in controller file in my handleBeforeRebindTable method:

```
var mBindingParams = oEvent.getParameter("bindingParams");
mBindingParams.sorter = [new sap.ui.model.Sorter("Quantity")];
```

This allows me to sort my table in ascending order.

Answer (score 2):

If you are binding the data model for the aggregation **items** in **"/"** path, just add the sorter in the **XML view** itself as below.

```
<Table items="{
           path : '/',
           sorter : {
              path : 'Quantity' 
           }
      }">
    <columns>
        <Column>
            <header>
                <Text text="Quantity">
            </header>
        </Column>    
        <Column>
            <header>
                <Text text="Order">
            </header>
        </Column>
     </columns>
     <ColumnListItem type="Navigation">
         <Link class="sapMLabelBold" text="{Quantity}"></Link>
         <Link class="sapMLabelBold" text="{Order}"></Link>
     </ColumnListItem>
</Table>
```

By default, the sorting is **ascending**, but you could also add a property **descending** with the value true inside the sorter property to change the sorting order.

Comment: Hi Naveen,

I tried it, however it throws an error and says "The Data Services Request could not be understood due to malformed syntax"

Comment: I have a smart table on top of responsive table, and my data is coming from entity set mentioned in smart table.